Time difference between peaks of Lotka-Volterra equations
In the Lotka-Volterra equations:
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = \phantom{-}\alpha x - \beta xy\\
\frac{dy}{dt} & = - \gamma y + \delta xy
\end{align}
The peak of the predator population occurs after a short time lag from the peak of the prey population.
I'm trying to find the exact time difference.
I've found the period of the elliptical orbit already through linearization, and I've found the time difference numerically using $\tt MATLAB$ already but would now like to attempt this analytically.
Is this even possible, and if so, how? Thanks!

What kind of solution are you looking for? Does it have to be in closed form, can it be numerical, a series, explicit, inexplicit, ...?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations#A_simple_example

Here is a procedure for obtaining a series solution: Jörg Waldvogel. The Period in the Volterra-Lotka Predator-Prey Model. SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis, Dec., 1983, Vol. 20, No. 6, pp. 1264-1272 (PDF link)
